# How can I add an overload for the Object.entries function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a custom type, `SpecialRecord<K,V>` and want to define how `Object.entries` behaves on it. This is similar to how, somewhere, there is a definition for how `Object.entries` behaves on a `Record` type.

I've tried overloading the method in a global .d.ts file, but it doesn't seem to take this definition. Plus, I'd want to extend the definition, not override it entirely.

```
interface Object {
    entries<K, V>(obj: SpecialRecord<K,V>): [K,V][]
}
```

If I instead call it `xentries` and then use `xentries` it passes typing. This is an indication that the file is being loaded (but of course this would fail at runtime).

How can I properly add an additional type to Object.entries?

Comment: I would not overload `Object.entries` but create a utility function which uses `Object.entries`

Comment: @HTN That's what I'm doing now, but I'd like to know how to override Object.entries anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`entries()` is defined in ObjectConstrutor, so you can do:

```js
interface MyInt {
  foo: string;
}

interface ObjectConstructor {
  entries(obj: MyInt): ['foo', string];
}

const myobj: MyInt = {foo: 'a'};
const t = Object.entries(myobj);
```